# How to add show functionality to each item in index list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently click a button to show some info, but the info only appears below the button of the first item. I want it to appear below each corresponding button in my index of items.

Appreciate any tips on debugging.

Please see JS code below:

```js
$(function(){
  homeButton();
  profileButton();
  readMoreButton();
});

function readMoreButton(){
  $(document).on('click', 'button.read-more.btn-more', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    appendReadMore(this.attributes.href.value)
  });
}

function appendReadMore(url){
  $.get(url, function (result){
    $("#ReadMoreSpan").html("Location:"+result[0].location);
  });
}

function iterateJobs(jobs){
  var str = "<ul>";
  jobs.forEach(function(job){
    var job_id = job.id;
    var link_path = '/repairmen/' + job['repairman']['id'] + '/jobs/' + job['id'];
    str += '<li>Repairman: ' + job['repairman']['name'] + '<br>';
    str += 'Customer: ' + job['customer']['name'] + '<br>';
    str += '<ul>';
    str += iterateTickets(job['tickets']);
    str += '</ul>';
    str += '<button class="edit btn-info" href="' + link_path + '/edit">Edit Job</button>  |  ';
    str += '<button ' + `id=${job_id} ` + 'class="delete btn-danger" href="' + link_path + '">Delete Job</button> | ';
    str += '<button class="read-more btn-more" href="' + link_path + '">Read More</button> <br><br>';
str+='<span id="ReadMoreSpan" ></span>';
    str += '</li>';
  });
  str += '</ul>';
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you'll end up with multiple `spans` with the same id (`#ReadMoreSpan`), so whenever you call your function it will put the result of the AJAX call into the first one. You need to do two things:

- Give all read more spans a unique ID so they can be identified
- Pass that id to the event handler for the link click.

Let's start with the ID and add that as a data-parameter on the span (and also remove the `#ReadMoreSpan`, as ID's should be unique:

```
str += '<span data-job="' + job_id + '"></span>';
```

Having done that, we need to be able to access this id when fetching more data, so add the same ID to the button:

```
str += '<button class="read-more btn-more" data-job="' + job_id + '" href="' + link_path + '">Read More</button> <br><br>';
```

Now the two functions can be updated to handle this value:

```
function readMoreButton() {
  $(document).on('click', 'button.read-more.btn-more', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    appendReadMore(this.attributes.href.value, this.getAttribute('data-job'))
  });
}

function appendReadMore(url, jobId) {
  $.get(url, function (result){
    $("span[data-job='" + jobId + "']").html("Location:"+result[0].location);
  });
}
```